# Atom g++ compiling package?

Tags: compiler, atom.io

I would like to know if there is a g++ compiling package that allows me to **compile and run** my c++ programs directly *in* Atom.

A GUI tool might be a bless.

Also is there a terminal emulator cause I could control my Linux terminal there without opening another window.

I'm using the latest Atom build and after trying many terminal packages it shows deprication cop errors:

[image: Atom]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package called **gpp-compiler**.

You can install it using the command line if you're running Linux:

```
apm install gpp-compiler
```

Otherwise, you can find the package here:
https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler